# Windows service to dismiss legal disclaimer

Tags: windows-xp

Is there a way push a keystroke to the legal text dialog using a windows service?

I looked in the windows xp boot sequence wiki

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_startup_process

These two items were of interest to me...

Starts the kernel-mode side of the Win32 subsystem (win32k.sys). This allows Windows to switch into graphical mode as there is now enough infrastructure in place.

Starts the user-mode side of the Win32 subsystem, the Client/Server Runtime Server Subsystem (csrss.exe). This makes Win32 available to user-mode applications.

I was thinking a windows service would start up soon enough to detect the open windows, but i do not seem to be able to grab that window handle...

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

The local security policy that displays the legal text is locked by AD and i do not have access to remove it, and IT does not want to move it into the "normal" location of the registry, and out of the local security policy.

Comment: If your IT dept. maintains your AD and policies, and they do not want to alter the registry to do this (quite wisely), then why would you have the authority to do this?  Also, what is this legal text dialog you speak of and why would you want it automated without going through and making sure you agree with it?

Comment: >>If your IT dept. maintains your AD and policies, and they do not want to alter the registry to do this (quite wisely), 
The legal text is NOT in the registry (where it should be) it is in the local security policy.

Comment: >>then why would you have the authority to do this? 
Due to the requirements of the autoadminlogin application request, this legal box is blocking everything from running on the machine until the user manually presses the OK button.
The project contridicts the established business rules (legal textbox) requirements. Thus my application is in a gridlock, and i am looking for alternate routes to complete the application.

Comment: >>Also, what is this legal text dialog you speak of 
If you do not know what the legal dialog message box is, then why are you questioning my question?

Comment: >>and why would you want it automated without going through and making sure you agree with it?
The project requirements need to reboot the machine early in the morning, and prelauch the application the people use in the morning.

Comment: This is an administrative problem, not a technical one. You need to work with your IT department to get an exemption for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows service does not get executed until the user accepts the legal dialog.  It seems the entire computer is waiting on this modal dialog to the acknowledged before it continues the boot process.